# arrange index of elements with highest double value in array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, nullpointerexception

So I have an array with 30 probabilities values as double. I want to

1. first check for highest element in array
2. store its index in a new Array
3. repeat the first step by excluding the element that has been checked before

I am trying to do it by replacing the checked element to null and repeating the step 1 by checking all elements except null. But this gives me Null pointer exception. Even though I am creating a Double object of Array.

```
Double[] P_array= {0.23, 0.45, 0.1, 0.65, 0.67};
int maxIndex = 0;
int[] index_sorting  = new int[P_array.length]; 
int sort_index  = 0; 
for (int i = 1; i < P_array.length; i++){
    if (P_array[i] != (null)){    //getting NPE exception here
    if ((P_array[i] > P_array[maxIndex])){
        maxIndex = i;
        System.out.print(new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format(P_array[i]));
         System.out.print(",");
         P_array[maxIndex]= null;   //also getting NPE exception here
         index_sorting[sort_index] = maxIndex;
         sort_index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any better way of achieving the task, other than replacing the element with null?

Comment: on which line you are getting the exception?

Comment: So, you want to have an array of indices, and have this array sorted by descending order of the matching double values, is that right? So [1.0, 2.0, 0.0] would give [1, 0, 2]?

Comment: @reek updated answer...

Comment: @JB yes I want like that

Comment: probably you are getting npe while comparing a null to a double.

Comment: @Reek I tried if (P_array[i] !=  (Double null)) ... and  P_array[maxIndex]= (Double)null; ... but same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much easier and faster way to do that, yes. Just create an array of indices, and sort it according to their matching double value:

```
double[] array = new double[] {2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0};

Integer[] result = new Integer[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = i;
}
Arrays.sort(result, Comparator.<Integer>comparingDouble(index -> array[index]).reversed());

System.out.println("result = " + Arrays.toString(result));
// [1, 0, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    double[] array = new double[] {2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0};

    Integer[] result = IntStream.range(0, array.length).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
    Arrays.sort(result, Comparator.<Integer> comparingDouble(i -> array[i]).reversed());

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Comment: Output: [1, 0, 3, 2]